# Set maximum consumer count jms solace

Tags: java, spring, jms, solace

I am trying to set the maximum consumer count of a topic endpoint with jms using solace as a broker, so for increasing load, multiple instances of the app can be started in cloudfoundry, and multiple subscribers can consume messages of the same topic.

I have tried multiple combinations of the below settings (`setConcurrency(), setConcurrentConsumers(), setMaxConcurrentConsumers()`, (20 as an arbitrary high number). Judging from the documentation, I definitely need to use `setMaxConcurrentConsumers()` and set this to an appropriately high value.

When I deploy the app, the topic endpoint gets created, but when I look at the solace management interface, the maximum consumer count is always 1 (as can be seen here: `Queues -> Topic Endpoints -> select endpoint -> Configured Limit`), even though it should be 20. So the second consumer is not able to connect. I don't want to set this manually every time I deploy the app.

[image: Screenshot of my solace management interface]

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SolaceController.class);

    @Value("${durable_subscription}")
    private String subscriptionName;

    @Value("${topic_name}")
    private String topic_name;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        JmsTemplate jmst = new JmsTemplate(ccf);
        jmst.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return jmst;
    }

    @Bean
    public Session configureSession(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        return connectionFactory.createConnection().createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }


    private TextMessage lastReceivedMessage;

    public class SimpleMessageListener implements MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                lastReceivedMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                try {
                    logger.info("Received message : " + lastReceivedMessage.getText());
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    logger.error("Error getting text of the received TextMessage: " + e);
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("Received message that was not a TextMessage: " + message);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer orderMessageListenerContainer() {

        DefaultMessageListenerContainer lc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        lc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        lc.setDestinationName(topic_name);
        lc.setMessageListener(new SimpleMessageListener());
        lc.setDurableSubscriptionName(subscriptionName);
        lc.setPubSubDomain(true);

        //tried multiple combinations here, also setting only setMaxConcurrentConsumers
        lc.setConcurrency("2-20");
        lc.setConcurrentConsumers(20);
        lc.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);

        lc.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        lc.initialize();
        lc.start();
        return lc;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it change if you comment out setSubscriptionDurable(true) ?  Maybe you are always using the same subscription name and Solace doesn't like that ?

Comment: Just tried this out. Four topic endpoints (to the same topic) are created, in the case of two application instances, which is fine for me. Also no errors of subscribers not being able to connect in the log output. All of them of course non-durable, but I need durable subscriptions, there is absolutely no way around it. No message must be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think for your use case, your consumer is stuck with queues. See https://solace.com/blog/topic-subscription-queues/

"... while multiple consumers can bind to Queues
Durable endpoints are limited to a single topic subscription. Queues allow multiple topic subscriptions as well as topic wildcards."

If you don't want to change your publisher you can try "Topic Subscription on Queues". That is a queue can be configured to listen on a topic. And then your consumers would get messages from that queue.

Comment: So after digging around, I've found out that this is a solace-specific feature, so a solace-specific Session is needed to subscribe a queue to a topic...but I'm trying to be as broker-agnostic as possible, so I can switch it easily later if necessary. Unfortunately I didn't include this requirement in the question.

Comment: yeah, good idea to be broker-agnostic. This is JMS after all. So how about using queues ?

Comment: But what if I have a message producer that publishes some message and does not want to care in which queue to put it exactly? He just wants to publish it, declare what it's about (topic) and whoever subscribes to this topic can grab it. I'm talking about the foundation of a rather complex multiservice system.
I don't see queues fit for that use case. Or do you?

Comment: well, how about using non-durable topics and transactions then ? Also with transacted publications and consumptions you wouldn't risk loosing messages.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. I've tried this, ending up with two topic endpoints if I have two instances, and the message will go to both instances, which is not what I want, I need only one instance to receive a message.

Comment: If you have multiple receivers, but only one of them should receive the message I can think of 4 ways to achieve this: use a queue (probably the best), use 'topic subscription on a queue' (provider-specific), publish to consumer-specific topics A.1, A.2, A.1, A.2 or let the consumer ignore messages not intended for it: for example one consumer ignores the message if JMSTimestamp%2==0 and the other if JMSTimestamp%2==1 - this gives you load-balancing but not fault-tolerance...

Comment: Ok, so the second way seems to be the most appropriate one. I've looked through all the solace api guide for an example of "topic subscription on a queue" in java, but couldn't find one. I want to set it programmatically, not with the CLI, but I'm not sure if that's even possible. Do you happen to know that?

Comment: programatically is not easy, as you can imagine. There's something called SEMP REST API which might help you. But since you have to do the setup only once, I'd recommend to set it up through CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a non-exclusive queue/endpoint.

By default, the queue you create are exclusive queues/endpoints, which means only one subscriber can bind to it at any time.

The easiest way to create such a queue/endpoint is through the Solace CLI.

To create a non-exclusive queue in your JMS program, you have to go into Solace specific JMS implementation like this:

```
    if (queueName != null) {
        EndpointProperties props = new EndpointProperties();
        props.setAccessType(EndpointProperties.ACCESSTYPE_NONEXCLUSIVE);

        try {
            ((SolConnection)connection).getProperties().getJCSMPSession()
                .provision(JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createQueue(queueName), props, 0L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One very important requirement, as also stated in the question, is that everything is supposed to happen programmatically, so no CLI set up should be involved.

Comment: I created a non-exclusive queue by going inside the JCSMP... I will update the answer above.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for getting back! Could you please provide a fully working code sample that you've used to get this snippet running? And more specifically: how to connect this newly created queue to the topic which I created with the code in my question. Also I'm not sure which `connection` are you casting to a `SolConnection` in line 6?